# Sum of univalent functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f,g$ be a pair of univalent functions on a proper subdomain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb C$. Does their sum $f+g$ necessarily omit any complex value?
Similarly, can all holomorphic function be written as sums of univalent functions?

Comment: No to both in as simple domain as the unit disk. 1) $(1-z)^{-2}-(1+z)^{-2}$ 2) Univalent functions cannot grow too fast near the boundary.

Comment: Or `$z$` and `$1/z$` on `${\bf C} - \{0\}$`.